# Whats this difference between [[NSUUID new] UUIDString] & CFUUIDRef

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier, nsuuid

Can Anyone let me know what is the difference between creating the Unique Id by these two implementations give below

1)

```
  CFUUIDRef cfuuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    NSString *udidString = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, cfuuid));
```

2)     `NSString *guid = [[NSUUID new] UUIDString];`

Which one is more reliable as I am working on app from IOS 8 and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find details on [NSHipster's uuid-udid-unique-identifier post](http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/).

In the interest of *not* posting 'link only' answer here are excerpts form the same article:

> NSUUID was added to Foundation in iOS 6 as a way to easily create
>   UUIDs.
>
> If your app targets iOS 5 or earlier, however, you have to settle for
>   Core Foundation functions on CFUUIDRef

To sum up, although both return a valid UUID, go ahead and use NSUUID as its easier.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, shall use the same:)

Answer (score 1):

`NSUUID` was added to Foundation in iOS 6 as a way to easily create UUIDs.

`CFUUIDRef` is a Core Foundation function. If your app targets iOS 5 or earlier, you should go with this.

So, for iOS 8 and above, you should use `NSUUID` for the sake of simplicity and convenience.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, shall use the same:)

Comment: Always happy to help :). Could you please accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple

1.If your app targets iOS 5 or below iOS 5,it belongs to CoreFoundation
  also you need to set

```
CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
NSString *UUID = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
```

2.If you app targets iOS6 or above iOS 6,it belongs to Foundation also you need to set

```
NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```